# LocationClient setMockMode and setMockLocation are not defined?

Tags: android, mocking, android-geofence, location-client

Been playing with android geofences but testing is becoming an issue. I need to mock the device location in order to trigger the enter/leave events but so far I am unable to find a way to do this.

In the documentation of the LocationClient there are two methods that seem to do what I need:

- [setMockLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#setMockLocation%28android.location.Location%29)
- [setMockMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#setMockMode%28boolean%29)

but I cannot compile any project with those methods as the compiler complains these symbols do not exists:

```
  SujGeoService2.java:296: error: cannot find symbol
    mLocClient.setMockMode(true);
              ^
  symbol:   method setMockMode(boolean)
  location: variable mLocClient of type LocationClient
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to latest google-play-services (revision 12 now) from the Android SDK Manager and it will works fine.

Comment: The problem was that the Google Repository did not have yet the latest library versions. I reported this and the latest version (rev. 3) contains the correct libraries. Since I used the repo (via gradle) and not the libraries directly I had this issue.

Comment: You can download the latest version of google-play-services library project away from Android SDK Manager and then import it to the eclipse projects.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't figure it out already, just use the latest version of the google-play-services (revision 10).

Comment: I have the latest google-play-services revision (10) installed and still get this compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and setting a newer version of Play Services (4.0.30) in my build.gradle resolved the issue for me.

Don't forget to add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` in case it isn't there yet:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```